# Keras tensorflow with R stops after some epochs

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, training-data

Working with Rscript vers 4.2.0 and tensorflow 2.0.0. After some epochs, the training freezes. Any idea the cause of that issue?

```
batch_size <- 256
# Fit data into model
history <- model_big %>%
  fit(
    # training data
    train_image_array_gen,

    # training epochs
    steps_per_epoch = as.integer(train_samples / batch_size),
    epochs = 10,

    # validation data
    validation_data = val_image_array_gen,
    validation_steps = as.integer(valid_samples / batch_size),
    
    callback = list(
    callback_early_stopping(monitor = 'val_loss',min_delta = 0.0005, patience = 3,mode = 'min')),
  verbose = 1
  )
```

I tried to remove `validation_steps = as.integer(valid_samples / batch_size)` and `steps_per_epoch = as.integer(train_samples / batch_size)` but with no luck.

Comment: Just so you know, Tensorflow 2.0.0 is quite old by now and no longer officially supported. Additionally, TF 2.0 had some security-related patch releases, and if you really need to be on 2.0, it's recommended you use version 2.0.4

Comment: Thanks. I will upgrade tensorflow 2.0.0 to 2.0.4,let's see if it resolves the issue.